# Modifying a JMS message before its sent to dead letter queue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic11g, java-ee-5

I am using a `MDB` to process a `JMS` message. In case of an exception, I would ideally want to stamp a `JMS` message with the error detail as well (exception message) and allow it proceed to a dead letter queue (configured in Weblogic server).

In the catch block, I mutated the `JMS` Message object as follows

```
msg.clearProperties();
msg.setStringProperty("error", e.getMessage());
```

and threw a `RuntimeException` which marked the message consumption process as failed and hence it moved to a failed request queue (I configured Weblogic NOT to REDELIVER the message)

As per configuration, the message fails goes to the failed request queue - however the 'error' property was not included. Having read `JMS` 1.1 spec doc, it says that the a redelivered `JMS` message will have the 'original' content. In this case, I have forced Weblogic not to redeliver it - not sure why I cant see the custom property which I set on the message

Is this expected? If yes, any workarounds?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you rollback the transaction. You cannot roll back a JMS transaction and still make changes to the message.

What you should do is instead manually sending the modified message to an error queue in the same transaction. In that case, you cannot throw exceptions from your MDB.

Comment: Agree. In addition, consider to use MQDLH.
Dead Letter Queue is well defined in WebSphere MQ, they define some Dead-letter header (MQDLH) - https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q096110_.htm
Use them (and do not clear previous properties) can help administrator to perform analyse or to replay the message later.